# JAXB, Custom bindings, Adapter1.class and Joda-time

Tags: java, binding, annotations, jaxb

I have a problem with the way JAXB is generating the bound classes for an XML schema (which, for sake of precision, I cannot modify).
I want to map a xsd:date type to a Joda-time LocalDate object and, reading [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501581/wsdl-customization-xmlgregoriancalender-to-java-util-date) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666988/in-jaxb-how-to-use-xmljavatypeadapters-annotation), I created the following DateAdapter class:

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String,LocalDate> {
    private static DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");

    public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return fmt.parseLocalDate(v);
    }

    public String marshal(LocalDate v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString("yyyyMMdd");
    }
}
```

And I added the following to my global binding file:

```
  <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxb:javaType name="org.joda.time.LocalDate" xmlType="xs:date"
            parseMethod="my.classes.adapters.DateAdapter.unmarshal"
            printMethod="my.classes.adapters.DateAdapter.marshal" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
```

The problem is that, when I try to maven compile my project, it fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] \My\Path\MyProject\target\generated-sources\xjc\my\classes\generated\Adapter1.java:[20,59] non-static method unmarshal(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context
[ERROR] \My\Path\MyProject\target\generated-sources\xjc\my\classes\generated\Adapter1.java:[24,59] non-static method marshal(org.joda.time.LocalDate) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

...and this is where things get weird.
JAXB generates a class Adapter1 that contains the following:

```
public class Adapter1
    extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate>
{


    public LocalDate unmarshal(String value) {
        return (my.classes.adapters.DateAdapter.unmarshal(value));
    }

    public String marshal(LocalDate value) {
        return (my.classes.adapters.DateAdapter.marshal(value));
    }

}
```

....which is the source of the compilation error.

Now, my questions are:

- being that my adapter is overriding XmlAdapter, I cannot make the methods static....how do I avoid this?
- Can I avoid the generation of Adapter1.class altogether?? Maybe using package-level annotation XmlJavaTypeAdapters, and if so, how do I do it exactly?? (JAXB generates already a package-info.java of its own....)

Hope I made my situation clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to extend `XmlAdapter`.

Just create static methods on a POJO and it will work.

Example:

```
 public class DateAdapter {
    private static DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");

    public static LocalDate unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return fmt.parseLocalDate(v);
    }

    public static String marshal(LocalDate v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString("yyyyMMdd");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 21):

I was in a WSDL first context: no java at all, just generate a CXF Client from a provided WSDL.

I was stuck with the ugly `Adapter1.java` for a long time, but I found the solution [there](https://web.archive.org/web/20150125085421/http://blog.steveperkins.info/2011/01/changing-jaxb-generated-adapter-classes/).

You will use a custom XMLAdapter like already explained.

The key of this problem was adding the `xjc` extension to the global binding file:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
 jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
       <xjc:javaType adapter="com.xxx.tools.xjc.DateAdapter" 
        name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**xjc** extension allow the usage of `xjc:javaType` that accept **adapter** parameter. No more static method required !

**Note** this seems to work with jaxb 2.1+ only.

Comment: Think there is typo with missing D in xmlType="xs:dateTime".
I had to change it to xmlType="xsd:dateTime"

Comment: I guess it depends on what you have on the namespace declaration. In the exemple it is `xmlns:xs` :)

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to extend `XmlAdapter` and with Joda-Time v2, you do not even need to implement static methods, as they are already provided.

```
<jaxb:javaType xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
    name="org.joda.time.LocalDate"
    xmlType="xs:date"
    parseMethod="org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse"
    printMethod="java.lang.String.valueOf"
/>
```

See [JAXB datatype converters for xs:date xs:time and xs:dateTime](https://sourceforge.net/p/joda-time/feature-requests/82/)

Comment: this should be the new correct answer.  the one that is marked correct works but as stated in this answer, _you don't even have to define any classes at all_

Comment: it works for old version, in new version it says : cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'adapter' must appear on element 'xjc:javaType'

Answer (score 3):

When generating XmlAdapters from an XML schema you need to put the logic for the conversion in static methods not in an `XmlAdapter`.  This is so an `XmlAdapter` that leverages that logic can be generated.  I recognize that this is an odd mechanism.

**Complete Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html

Answer (score 3):

You are extending `XmlAdapter` which is used when you want to annotation your Java model for JaxB, that is through the annotation `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1.class)`. For your case you just need a class with static methods that does not extend `XmlAdapter`. You will need the parse method (take a string and return date) and print method (take a date and return a string) and that's about it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution as useful
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

You will create an adapter

```
package blog.jodatime;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class DateTimeAdapter 
    extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime>{

    public DateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        //return new DateTime(v); - old solution that didn't properly handled the timezone
        return DateTime.parse(v);
    }

    public String marshal(DateTime v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString();
    }

}
```

Then register it with annotations by defining a blog/jodatime/package-info.java in your sources

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({ @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = DateTime.class, value = JodaDateTimeJaxbAdapter.class) })
package blog.jodatime;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;

import org.joda.time.*;
```

Then you should expect that the serialization of DateTime is done without any other changes, just don't forget to annotate your class with @XmlRootElement.

Comment: What if I'm generating my `JAXB` classes with `xjc`? My annotation would get overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

A complete example. This is your bindings.xml:

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="YourWsdl"
      xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
      xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
      jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='YourTargetNameSpace']">
       <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <xjc:javaType adapter="com.xxx.your.package.DateAdapter" name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime" />
       </jxb:globalBindings>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

plus the Java Class:

```
package com.yourpackage;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date>
{

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(final String date) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseDate(date).getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(final Date date)
    {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return DatatypeConverter.printDate(calendar);
    }

}
```

plus the pom.xml definition:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <defaultOptions>
                    <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
                </defaultOptions>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/your.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                            <extraargs>-xjc-npa</extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-xjc-Xsetters</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                        <bindingFiles>
                        <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/binding.xml</bindingFile>
                        </bindingFiles>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```